# Is it possible to connect 9 blue leds to a 9 volt battery?

Tags: led, batteries, resistors

My plan is to connect 3 series of 3 blue leds in parallel, all connected to a 9 volt battery. Would this be possible to do without a resistor? Because from what i read, blue leds use 3 volts
Here's a rough sketch of what i want to do. Any help is appreciated 
[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet for the LEDs. We need to see the specifications for them.

Comment: Nogt a real design question! Of course it is possible.

Comment: Why are 7 of the LED's shorted out?

Comment: Well, of course it's possible.. but would it work? Ask yourself what happens if your 9v battery isn't exactly 9v. Or if your LED forward voltage isn't exactly 3v for every single diode..

Comment: @Elliot, if the OP didn't say anything, I think that is very reasonable to think that he/she is talking about generic LEDs, there's no need to see a datasheet to answer this question thinking about the specs of a generic LED.

Comment: @Galo, a rule of thumb for a novice: NEVER connect LEDs without a resistor; LEDs are just like aquarium fishes: they will eat everything that you feed to them. It could be possible to do what you are asking, in special circunstances, but, if you need to ask about, you should not be trying to do this kind of thing. Three series of 3 LEDs each, let's assume that each series runs with 10 mA, would draw 30 mA. Maybe it is too much for a 9v battery? Whatever, put a resistor of 22 ohms in each LED series, this will not lower the voltage so much, but will guarantee more lifespan to your leds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Whether you want to do that is another thing.

9V batteries can have more than 9.5V when new and are considered empty around 5V.

Blue LEDs have approximately 3V forward voltage, but it won't be exactly 3.0V and it will vary due to manufacturing tolerances etc.

So assuming all the LEDs have exactly 3.0V forward voltage at their rated current, a fresh battery with 9.5V connected to 3 LEDs can give the LEDs quite high current so that their useful life is reduced, or they might burn out immediately.

And assuming the battery voltage has dropped to say 7V, maybe no LED will glow even if there is still energy left in the battery.

Also the LED manufacturing tolerances will cause the LED chain with smallest sum of LED forward voltages to be brighter than the other chains, and maybe the other LED chains won't light up at all.

So, in light of this, maybe you don't want to use chains of 3 LEDs without resistors on a 9V battery, even if it is possible.

Comment: I have red keychain LED lights that use one button cell (no resistor), and white keychain lights that use two button cells (no resistor). They work, but they unnecessarily use too much power when the batteries are new, and the brightness fades more than it should when the batteries are near depletion.

Comment: @Mattman944 Just to point out for the OP that the reason your keychain light works is due to the relatively high internal resistance of the button cell. Try that with a fresh AA alkaline battery with very little internal resistance and that LED is probably toast.